# How to set default innodb_buffer_pool_size before mysqldump and set it back to 1600M after mysqldump?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.7

I want to make backups every day automatically. It was fine when database was 700-800Mb, but now database (dumped sql file) is 1.5G and when using mysqldump it errors on random table with 2013 error.

When I comment out my setting of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, `mysqldump` works perfectly.

Is there nice way to set to defaults `innodb_buffer_pool_size` before `mysqldump` and then back to `1600M`?

---

p.s. I'm using mysqldump as following

```
mysqldump --max_allowed_packet=500M --net_buffer_length=548576 --single-transaction?
```

Comment: Please show the text of the 2013 error.

Comment: How much RAM do you have?  If less than 4GB, 1600M is too big!

Comment: 2GB. In some article was saying you should place 80-90% to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting [innodb_buffer_pool_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size) is dynamic in MySQL 5.7.

The default value for [innodb_buffer_pool_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size) is 128M (134217728).

All you need to do is the following:

```
mysql -uroot -p... -ANe"SET GLOBAL innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1024 * 1024 * 128;"
mysqldump ...
mysql -uroot -p... -ANe"SET GLOBAL innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1024 * 1024 * 1600;"
```

There may be bit of a pause depending on the number of dirty pages in the buffer pool and the active transactions using them.

Answer (score 1):

90% is dangerously high for any server.  For a "tiny" 2G, a much lower 500M should be safe.  Swapping is terrible for performance.  But, things are worse -- `--max_allowed_packet=500M` is taking up a terribly large amount of RAM.  Try `50M`.  If that gives an error, then raise it and lower the buffer_pool.